# Get path to the user home directory on Windows in PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to get the path to the current user's home directory (e.g. `C:\Users\User1`) while respecting different localizations of Windows (which have a different name for the `Users` folder).

I have seen solutions in Batch, but isn't there a clean way of doing it in PowerShell?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the environment variable `$env:USERPROFILE`.

For example:

```
cd "$env:USERPROFILE\Downloads"
```

will take you to the user's Downloads folder (given that it's named "Downloads").]

Comment: This works well, unless the user has changed the location (like to OneDrive) which can be done in the Downloads > Properties > Location tab. If someone moves it, there does not seem to be a universal way to get there (yet browser still seem to know...)